# Ruby API - Hash#map

Tags: ruby

I was doing an exercise and the solution was:

```
def solution(pairs)
  pairs.map{|k,v| "#{k} = #{v}"}.join(',')
end
```

my solution worked, but was different because in the Hash class doc I didn't find a method called `map`, it is present in the `Array` class but not the `Hash` one.
So the question is, how do I have to read the core ruby api? sometimes do I need to guess if a class has a method? Why isn't `map` method reported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Hash` included `Enumerable` module. And the `Hash#map` is actually `Enumerable#map`. Open your **IRB**, do as below I did, you will get all your answers. Look the documentation of [***Method***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Method.html) class.

```
h = {1=>2}
h.method(:map)
# => #<Method: Hash(Enumerable)#map>
h.method(:map).inspect
# => "#<Method: Hash(Enumerable)#map>"
h.method(:map).owner
# => Enumerable
```